# Keras : slice index 10 of dimension 1 out of bounds error

Tags: keras, lstm

Below is my code to run LSTM model using keras:

```
epochs = 10
batch_size = 16
MAX_NB_WORDS = 50000
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 250
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

inputs = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],))
x = Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM)(inputs)
x = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(x)
x = LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)(x)
logits = Dense(5)(x)
variance_pre = Dense(1)(x)
variance = Activation('softplus', name='variance')(variance_pre)
logits_variance = concatenate([logits, variance], name='logits_variance')
softmax_output = Activation('softmax', name='softmax_output')(logits)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[logits_variance,softmax_output])
model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=0.001),
    loss={
    'logits_variance': bayesian_categorical_crossentropy(100, 10),
    'softmax_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'
    },
    metrics={'softmax_output': metrics.categorical_accuracy},
    loss_weights={'logits_variance': .2, 'softmax_output': 1.})

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs,
batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
patience=3, min_delta=0.0001)])
```

X_train shape is (2002, 250) and Y_train shape is (2002, 5)

I get below error when I run above model:

> ValueError: slice index 10 of dimension 1 out of bounds. for 'loss_34/logits_variance_loss/strided_slice_1' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,6], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0 10>, input[2] = <0 11>, input[3] = <1 1>.

Please help on what could be the issue with the model.

Comment: Your model has two outputs therefore when you train (fit) your model you should pass a list of two labels, i.e. one for logits and another for variance.